# How to implement a process to run every 5 minutes inside a flask server to check everything is okay?

Tags: multithreading, flask, multiprocessing

I have a web interface built by flask which needs to flush one of its dictionaries every 5 minutes. How can I code this feature in? I have looked up threading, multiprocessing and Asyncio almost all examples are about complicated stuff and none of them is relevant to my very simple basic need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advanced Python Scheduler can do this for you and it is easy to use. It runs within the application and runs jobs that you schedule at intervals.

```
job = scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'interval', minutes=5)
```

The [documentations](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html) are clear and easy to setup. Also you can find [Flask-APScheduler](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-APScheduler/) which is almost the same with few flask features.